# arcgis.content.search list index out of range

Tags: list, indexing, arcgis

im trying to do the tutorial here:

> https://developers.arcgis.com/python/sample-notebooks/land-cover-classification-using-unet/

and when you do the first bit :

> label_layer = gis.content.search("title:
> Kent_county_full_label_land_cover owner:api_data_owner", "Map Image
> Layer")[0] # the index might change label_layer

you immediately get:

> IndexError: list index out of range

but this can't be right because [0] should correlate to the first and only item of the layer

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting that error is because "Kent_county_full_label_land_cover" doesn't exist in your content/the "GIS" you are connecting to.

You can add this item to your own content. Go to Content ==> Add Item ==> From URL and add this - https://pythonapi.playground.esri.com/server/rest/services/Kent_county_full_label_land_cover/MapServer

Once you copy it to your content. Just search for it like this (don't include owner:api_data_owner because you won't find the item if you search for that owner in your own content)

```
label_layer = gis.content.search("title: Kent_county_full_label_land_cover",  "Map Image Layer")[0]
```